Could there be any homotopy group without "Lebesgue Number Lemma"?
This is about a comment that I have made in my general topology class while I was proving the abovementioned lemma as a consequence of compactness!
As far as I know, essentially, there is only one proof of the fact that
$$\pi_1S^1\simeq\mathbb{Z}$$
which depends on path-lifting and homotopy-lifting lemmata. Both of these lemmata, being the main tools in the theory of covering spaces, depend on the Lebesgue number to construct the liftings inductively. Consequently, it seems to me that the very basic machinery in the theory of covering spaces, or their counterparts when one tries to compute the fundamental group through action of discrete groups, were not available if we did not have the Lemma of Lebesgue. Therefore, noting that any higher homotopy group could be considered as the fundamental group of some iterated loop space, we could not have a reasonable computation of some higher homotopy groups without this lemma!
I wonder, if I am wrong, where the false claims of my argument live?

I'm not sure there is a precise enough question to answer here. It is nearly impossible to argue things of the sort "you cannot prove X without using theorem Y", you can reformulate a proof of X to not use Y explicitly but that dissolves into the question of whether it is implicitly used anywhere. From what I recall the proofs I have seen do not use Lebesgue numbers explicitly, for instance, but you can probably argue that "really" they are used there.

There are several proofs that $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ that do not require covering space theory. One can also compute $\pi_n(S^n)$ for $n>1$ without knowing $\pi_1(S^1)$.

Even with the universal cover, one does not need Lebesgue numbers for $S^1$ since there are explicit evenly covered sets available (any open set $\not= S^1$).

@ConnorMalin could you please give examples or provide references!?

@ChristianRemling and you think the path and homotopy listings could exist with the Lemma?

@user51223 Both facts I stated can be proved by applications of the Hurewicz theorem. To be honest, I don't know precisely what point set topology is required to prove the Hurewicz theorem.

The fundamental group of the circle can be computed using the Fourier transform.

Probably the most radical way to avoid using any covering arguments is avoiding any topological spaces whatsoever, and working with simplicial sets instead. Pick your favourite Kan model of a circle, and voila. Another way would be to use van Kampen theorem in groupoid version.

@DenisT: the proofs of van Kampen that work with loops depend on the Lebesgue number, and the proofs that use covering spaces need the Lebesgue number to prove they are calculating the same thing as the usual fundamental group.  As far as simplicial sets go, if you want to prove that the simplicial set fundamental group is isomorphic to the usual one, I worry that something like simplicial approximation will show up, and that uses the Lebesgue number (but I’m less certain of this, and would have to think about it some more).

Thank for the wonderful comments, and your answer @AndyPutman. I feel the mention of $S^1$ in my question was somehow a mistake. The general question was about homotopy groups whose computations, in general, rely on covering space theory if we exclude pathological cases! That part of the theory, the construction of liftings, as far as I know depends on the Lebesgue number lemma. Could that be avoided too?

The Lebesgue Number Lemma is absolutely not needed to compute $\pi_1(S^1)$, or more generally to compute $\pi_n(S^n)$.  Here's one way to do it that I've actually used while teaching several times.
The first step is to convince yourself that for smooth manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$ equipped with basepoints, the set of homotopy classes of basepoint-preserving maps $M_1 \rightarrow M_2$ is the same as the set of smooth homotopy classes of basepoint-preserving smooth maps.  This is easy (e.g. just convolve with a mollifier), and is worth knowing regardless.
You now have several options.  The first is to do a baby version of the Pontrayagin-Thom argument to show that smooth maps $S^n \rightarrow S^n$ up to smooth homotopy are classified by their degrees.  This gives you $\pi_n(S^n) = \mathbb{Z}$.  Details can be found e.g. in Milnor's book on smooth manifolds.  Showing that $\pi_k(S^n) = 0$ for $k < n$ is even easier since smooth maps $S^k \rightarrow S^n$ cannot be surjective (by, say, Sard's lemma).
If you just want $\pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$, you can actually do it with covering spaces now without using the Lebesgue number argument.  Instead, you prove smooth path-lifting for the universal cover $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1$ by taking a smooth map $[0,1] \rightarrow S^1$ and integrating its velocity.
If you prefer to not use smooth methods, another option for computing $\pi_1(S^1)$ is to argue that since $S^1$ is a topological group, its fundamental group is abelian and hence is isomorphic to its first homology group (this doesn't use the Lebesgue number anywhere).  You then compute $H_1(S^1)$ using whatever tools you want.

That second paragraph is indeed a nice fact worth knowing on its own!

@NoahSchweber It is called the Whitney approximation theorem.

Existence of mollifiers obviously depends on finiteness of covering dimension.

@DenisT: I’m not sure exactly what you’re getting at.  Are you claiming that it needs Lebesgue numbers?  The proof I had in mind (which is the standard proof) can be found in these notes: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/21F-Manifolds/Notes/Lec11.pdf.  Can you point to where in that proof the issue lies?

Thank for the wonderful comments, and your answer @AndyPutman. I feel the mention of $S^1$
in my question was somehow a mistake. The general question was about homotopy groups whose computations, in general, rely on covering space theory if we exclude pathological cases! That part of the theory, the construction of liftings, as far as I know depends on the Lebesgue number lemma. Could that be avoided too?

@user51223: that’s a little vague.  If you literally want to know whether you need Lebesgue numbers to prove the most general version of the lifting theorem, then probably the answer is “yes” (though I’m not sure there’s a way to make that precise).  But for most specific computations, you can find devices that bypass that.  Is there a specific computation you are interested in?

@AndyPutman No, thee is not specific computation that I am after it. But, I always got the impression that there is “essentially” one way to compute the fundamental group of the circle, to start with, which is a kind of rigidity and the motivation for homotopy type theory!!? Perhaps, I am putting a sequence of vague statement together to make a deduction. However, having said these, I think for a class of important examples the Seifert-van Kampen theorem would be an imortant tool to compute $\pi_1$for which I think the Lebeshue number lemma is needed!

@user51223: Again, probably the Lebesgue number lemma is needed for the most general form of SvK, but in many (most?) specific examples you can avoid it.

By the way, you might be interested in the following very short proof of SvK (due to Grothendieck): https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/SeifertVanKampen.pdf

@user51223 The "synthetic" version of $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$ is not exactly the same assertion as the classical assertion that $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, it can't be proved in the same way. Everything in homotopy type theory is homotopy invariant, and the covering space map $\mathbb{R}\mapsto S^1$, which plays such an important role in the classical proof that $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$, is homotopic to a constant function, and therefore useless in homotopy type theory. Also, point-set topology (the Lebesgue number lemma) plays no role in homotopy type theory.

@TimothyChow Thank you so much for the clarifications.

The Lebesgue covering lemma is basically the statement that continuous functions on compact metric spaces are uniformly continuous. In that disguise, the lemma is a key ingredient for most of the analytical tools you mentioned (integration, approximation of continuous by smooth functions and surely also in Sard's theorem). The standard proof of the $\pi_1$-Hurewicz theorem is combinatorial, but the computation of $H_1 (S^1)$ relies on excision hence also on the covering lemma.

Lebesgue numbers are certainly not needed to compute $\pi_1(S^1)$ using lifting properties of covering spaces.  I checked eleven books that compute $\pi_1(S^1)$ using the covering space ${\mathbb R}\to S^1$ and only four used Lebesgue numbers.  The rest did not mention Lebesgue numbers and instead just used compactness.  Of course compactness is used to prove the Lebesgue number lemma, but that does not mean that Lebesgue numbers must be used to prove lifting properties.
Similarly, Lebesgue numbers are not needed to prove the general lifting properties in covering space theory, nor are they needed for the proof of the van Kampen theorem. Compactness arguments suffice in both these situations.
As an alternative to using covering spaces to compute $\pi_1(S^1)$ one can use a more general version of the van Kampen theorem that applies when a space is decomposed as the union of two path-connected subspaces whose intersection is not assumed to be path-connected.  In fact van Kampen's original 1932 paper includes such a generalization, although this seems to have been largely forgotten, as I have never seen this generalization mentioned in papers or books. (I am not talking about the use of groupoids to compute fundamental groups, which is quite a different story.) The more general van Kampen theorem deserves to be better known, and I will be including it in a revised version of my Algebraic Topology book that I am currently working on.

(I am not talking about the use of groupoids to compute fundamental groups, which is quite a different story.) — Could you please explain a bit what you want to clarify by this? Under goodness assumptions, the homotopy type of the union of two subspaces is the homotopy pushout of homotopy types of these two subspaces "along" the intersection, and the fundamental groupoid, being the first truncation of homotopy type, is also a homotopy pushout, and the Seifert–van Kampen theorem is talking about this, if I understand correctly.

@ Z.M. The more general van Kampen theorem in his 1932 paper does not make use of groupoids, which are a more recent concept that I believe arose (at least in topology) after category theory began to be developed.  Van Kampen's paper only talks about groups, particularly groups defined by generators and relations.
